# How to run apple and custom git side-by-side

Tags: macos, command-line, git

I have installed the Apple Developer Tools 5 on Mac OS X 10.9.4 which comes with Git:

```
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

I also have installed Git 2.0.1 using the [Mac OS X installer](http://www.git-scm.com/download/mac). How do I best set it up so that all applications use Git 2.0.1 by default? I could exchange the Apple Git binary for a symlink to the custom one. Alternatively I would have to modify the `PATH` so that it looks up the custom Git first. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Also, is that even a safe thing to do? Would anything, for instance XCode, break if I replaced Apple Git with Git 2.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've talked about modifying system tools before and the short of it is: don't do it! Things will use the system tools expecting a certain version of a certain tool and if you change that you could break many things.

Instead, change your path. For example, if your git is located at `/usr/local/git/bin/git`, add the following to your `~/.bash_profile` or equivalent:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

This way, you can use your git by running `git` but the system git will remain available.

Comment: That's what I thought, and I already went with the solution you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Extra hint... create an link to your custom git called "git2" somewhere on your path. Then you can use `$ git` or `$ git2` interchangeably

Comment: Also, use something like Homebrew for installing Git and similar tools. It will install them in `/usr/local/` by default, making it easy to switch between versions.